# Slurm MPI Error: An ORTE Daemon has failed

Tags: mpi, openmpi, slurm

I have been having some issues with Slurm and openMPI on a cluster. Whenever I run any job which uses `mpirun`, I get the following error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
An ORTE daemon has unexpectedly failed after launch and before
communicating back to mpirun. This could be caused by a number
of factors, including an inability to create a connection back
to mpirun due to a lack of common network interfaces and/or no
route found between them. Please check network connectivity
(including firewalls and network routing requirements).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This issue arose suddenly, and the problem seems to be ubiquitous across the compute nodes.

Seemingly related, `srun` is also now failing, with the message:

```
srun: error: Task launch for <jobid> failed on node <nodename>: Job credential expired
srun: error: Application launch failed: Job credential expired
srun: Job step aborted: Waiting up to 32 seconds for job step to finish.
```

Thanks for any help anyone might have!

EDIT: Adding an example

If I run `mpirun hostname` on the headnode, everything works fine. However, in a slurm allocation (`salloc`) when I run `mpirun hostname`, I get the error.

Comment: Write to your system administrators.

Comment: I will be fixing this, not a sysadmin. Do you have any ideas on how to fix the issue or what the root cause might be?

Comment: Try `srun hostname` within `salloc`. If it’s broken, then this is a SLURM issue.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet 
I tried `srun hostname` from an salloc, and that results in the same error as in the post for `srun`. I restarted one of the nodes, and got a message saying that the slurmd failed to start, so I logged into that node and ran `systemctl start slurmd.service` and it started it. After that, `systemctl start slurmd.service` indicates that the node daemon is working.

Comment: so this is a pure SLURM issue (e.g. `Open MPI` is out of the picture for now. Did you check all nodes are time synchronized?

Comment: I think this is probably the issue. The slurmctld.log is showing an error to that effect. Trying to figure out how to fix it now.

Comment: Yup, that was the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had difficulty because the slurm logs didn't have sufficient information.  Using OpenMPI-4.1.2, if you are running this via `mpiexec`, try the `-d` and `--debug-daemons` options.

E.g.

`mpiexec --d --np 2 ....`

and

`mpiexec --debug-daemons --np 2 ....`

This led me to discover some missing libraries that were required by `openmpi4/gcc/4.1.2/bin/orted`.

Look at the manpage for `mpiexec` for further debugging options.  It looks like `mpirun` has similar debugging options.